# Is there any way to open the regular editor for a code file from the diff view in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, diff

If I double click a file in Pending Changes, I get the diff view, which is nice, but sometimes I want to edit the file instead. Is there any way to bring up the regular editor from the diff view or from Pending Changes? What I've been doing is searching for the file in Solution Explorer, but that's kind of slow and I was hoping there was a way to bring up the editor directly from the diff view or from Pending Changes.

Answer (score 0):

The difference viewer built into Visual Studio provides a basic read only file view; so the answer is no ... not for out of the box Visual Studio tool. But not external applications.

---

I recommend that you use a purpose built diff viewer and specify it to be used by visual studio that will launch into the external program.

I personally have been using Araxis Merge which allows one to view/edit the local copy. It then allows you to save to the local file during a difference view.